Monogame says I don't have an XNB file, when I do
I have a function to load a list of images from a folder with the MonoGame Content.Load<Texture2D> () function. the code for the function is as follows:
void loadImageList(ref Texture2D[] spriteList, string folder)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < spriteList.Length; i++)
    {
        string fileName = folder + "/" + (i+1).ToString();
        spriteList[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(fileName);
    }
}

I call it like this:
Texture2D[] winOutline = new Texture2D[12];
loadImageList(ref winOutline, "winOutline");

This requires the folder to be set up like this:
Content
    winOutline
        1.png
        2.png
        3.png
        4.png
        5.png
        6.png
        7.png
        8.png
        9.png
        10.png
        11.png
        12.png

Normally, this works fine. In my game, I call this function several times for several different sprite sheets of varying length. Suddenly, when I added a 12th image to my winOutline folder, it stopped working and gave me this error message:
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: 'Asset does not appear to be a valid XNB file. Did you process your content for Windows?'

I checked the bin folder that MonoGame automatically makes, and winOutline/12.png does have an XNB file. When debugging, I also put a watch on the loadImageList function, and saw this:For every value of i from 0 to 10, spriteList is the correct file. When i = 11, the file should be {winOutline/12}, but instead it is null. The fileName variable is the correct "winOutline/12"
I tried rebuilding the file in the MGCB content editor multiple times, but it did nothing.
I'm out of ideas for what's happening.
EDIT:
I deleted and remade the image and it worked. I'm still leaving this question up in case anyone figures out what was happening, so that I can avoid the problem in the future.

"when I added a 12th image" - could it be you added it diferently? Compare project settings with working images. I guess missing file leads to same exception and you simply need to output this file.

@Sinatr No, a missing file leads to a different exception. I checked the image properties against an image that works properly, and they were the same.
